# how to remove item in recyclerview using volley?

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-recyclerview

Hi I have succeeded in inserting items by linking recycle view with MYSQL PHP, but erasing the items continues to fail. You can delete it on the client, but I keep failing with PHP and MYSQL. Can I get help with this example or code?

This is recyclerview adapter code

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    //Imageloader to load image
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Context context;

    //List to store all superheroes
    List<recyclerview_list> recyclerview_lists;

    //Constructor of this class
    public CardAdapter(List<recyclerview_list> recyclerview_lists, recyclerview context) {
        super();
        //Getting all superheroes
        this.recyclerview_lists = recyclerview_lists;
        this.context = (Context) context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_list, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        //Getting the particular item from the list
        recyclerview_list recyclerview_List = recyclerview_lists.get(position);

        //Loading image from url
        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(recyclerview_List.getImage_path(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView, R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

        //Showing data on the views
        holder.imageView.setImageUrl(recyclerview_List.getImage_path(), imageLoader);
        holder.textViewName.setText(recyclerview_List.getImage_name());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return recyclerview_lists.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //Views
        public NetworkImageView imageView;
        public TextView textViewName;
        public Button deleteButton;

        //Initializing Views
        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHero);
            textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            deleteButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);
            deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    delete(getAdapterPosition());


                }
            });

        }

        public void delete(int position) {

            try {
                recyclerview_lists.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is PHP code

```
$con = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");

$id = $_POST["id"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "DELETE FROM image WHERE id = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: you have not call any webservice for remove data from server.you have to call your PHP file when you press delete button.in current code it only removing item from local list

Comment: so i didn't know about how to call php file in adapter class.. is there any example ?

Answer (score 1):

Add new method in adapter call

```
  public void deleteFromServer(int id)
        {
         url = "http://yoururl/delete_image.php";
            StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, 
                new Response.Listener<String>() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // if success 
                        delete(id)
                        Log.d("Response", response);
                    }
                }, 
                new Response.ErrorListener() 
                {
                     @Override
                     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                         // error
                         Log.d("Error.Response", response);
                   }
                }
            ) {     
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() 
                {  
                        Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
                        params.put("id", id);  

                        return params;  
                }
            };
            queue.add(postRequest);
        }
```

Call this method from adapter class

```
deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    deleteFromServer(recyclerview_lists.get(getAdapterPosition()).id);


                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Good code, but can not fetch the recognized id. I will share my entire work.

Config.java

```
public static final String DATA_URL = "http:// /images/feed.php?page=";

/*Json으로 가져오는 이미지 테이블의 목록*/

// 이미지 주소
public static final String TAG_IMAGE_URL = "image_path";
// 이미지 이름
public static final String TAG_NAME = "image_name";
```

}

Custom volley Request.java

```
private static CustomVolleyRequest customVolleyRequest;
private static Context context;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;

private CustomVolleyRequest(Context context) {

    this.context = context;
    this.requestQueue = getRequestQueue();

    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue,
            new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                        cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                @Override
                public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                    return cache.get(url);
                }

                @Override
                public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    cache.put(url, bitmap);
                }
            });
}

public static synchronized CustomVolleyRequest getInstance(Context context) {
    if (customVolleyRequest == null) {
        customVolleyRequest = new CustomVolleyRequest(context);
    }
    return customVolleyRequest;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (requestQueue == null) {
        Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(context.getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 * 1024);
        Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
        requestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
        requestQueue.start();
    }
    return requestQueue;
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    return imageLoader;
}
```

}

recyclerview_list.java

```
private  String image_path;
private  String image_name;

public String getImage_path() {
    return image_path;
}

public void setImage_path(String image_path) {
    this.image_path = image_path;
}

public String getImage_name() {
    return image_name;
}

public void setImage_name(String image_name) {
    this.image_name = image_name;
}
```

recyclerview. java

//Creating a List of superheroes
    private List listSuperHeroes;

```
//Creating Views
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;


//Volley Request Queue
private RequestQueue requestQueue;

//The request counter to send ?page=1, ?page=2  requests
private int requestCount = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recyclerview);

    //Initializing Views
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    //Initializing our superheroes list
    listSuperHeroes = new ArrayList<>();
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Calling method to get data to fetch data
    getData();

    //Adding an scroll change listener to recyclerview
    recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(this);

    //initializing our adapter
    adapter = new CardAdapter(listSuperHeroes ,this);

    //Adding adapter to recyclerview
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

//Request to get json from server we are passing an integer here
//This integer will used to specify the page number for the request ?page = requestcount
//This method would return a JsonArrayRequest that will be added to the request queue
private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServer(int requestCount) {
    //Initializing ProgressBar
    final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    //Displaying Progressbar
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

    //JsonArrayRequest of volley
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Config.DATA_URL + String.valueOf(requestCount),
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //Calling method parseData to parse the json response
                    parseData(response);
                    //Hiding the progressbar
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //If an error occurs that means end of the list has reached
                    Toast.makeText(recyclerview.this, "No More Items Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    //Returning the request
    return jsonArrayRequest;
}

//This method will get data from the web api
private void getData() {
    //Adding the method to the queue by calling the method getDataFromServer
    requestQueue.add(getDataFromServer(requestCount));
    //Incrementing the request counter
    requestCount++;
}

//This method will parse json data
private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        //Creating the superhero object
        recyclerview_list recyclerviewList = new recyclerview_list();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            //Getting json
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            //Adding data to the superhero object
            recyclerviewList.setImage_path(json.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE_URL));
            recyclerviewList.setImage_name(json.getString(Config.TAG_NAME));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Adding the superhero object to the list
        listSuperHeroes.add(recyclerviewList);
    }

    //Notifying the adapter that data has been added or changed
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

//This method would check that the recyclerview scroll has reached the bottom or not
private boolean isLastItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 0) {
        int lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
        if (lastVisibleItemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && lastVisibleItemPosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//Overriden method to detect scrolling
@Override
public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
    //Ifscrolled at last then
    if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
        //Calling the method getdata again
        getData();
    }
}
```